# How to style the tabs in primary menu links in a Drupal 7 subtheme?

Tags: css, drupal, tabs, styling

I was just wondering what the general procedure is to style the tabs in the primary menu links. Where is the CSS that takes care of that? How can I change it? At the moment I have a Zen subtheme installed and I would like to completely restyle the tabs. The tabs' markup looks like this:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <h2 class="element-invisible">Primary tabs</h2>
  <ul class="tabs primary clearfix">
    <li class="active"><a href="/drupal/user/1" class="active">
       <span class="tab">View</span><span class="element-invisible">(active tab)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/drupal/user/1/venues"><span class="tab">Venues</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/drupal/user/1/events"><span class="tab">Events</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/drupal/user/1/edit"><span class="tab">Edit</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/drupal/user/1/shortcuts"><span class="tab">Shortcuts</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/drupal/user/1/devel"><span class="tab">Devel</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I would like is to be able to change the background colour of the tabs as tehy are now (they are greyish). I've tried setting the background colour of the spans, li, and a elements but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is inside the tabs.css in the Zen theme - can't believe I didn't see it before!